# Batch file: Trying to declare a variable for a directory or filename

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a command line where a user can perform certain tasks when typing certain words, but am a little confused at how I should declare the variables for directory and filenames.
This is what I have so far:

```
@echo off
echo Welcome to the Linux Bash Command Line simulator!
echo Enter your commands below
SET "v=%globalparam1%"
SET "path=%globalparam2%"
SET "file=%globalparam3%"
SET "v=%v%"
GOTO :vCheck
:vPrompt
SET /p "v=lcl> "
:vCheck
if not defined v goto :vPrompt
IF "%v%" == "ls" (
echo Using Windows command dir
dir
goto :vPrompt
)
IF "%v%" == "cp" (
echo Usage: cp sourcefile destinationfile
goto :vPrompt
)
IF "%v%" == "cp %file% %path%" (
echo Using Windows command copy %file% %path%
copy "%file%" "%path%"
goto :varPrompt
)
```

Also when I try to concatenate the strings, it gives me an "Unrecognized command" error. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Remove `@echo off` or comment it out, and run the batch file by opening a command prompt window and typing its path rather than double-clicking, then you can see what happens.

Comment: When I do this, I get :C:\...>REM @echo off

C:\...>echo Welcome to the Linux Bash Command Line simulator!
Welcome to the Linux Bash Command Line simulator!

C:\....>echo Enter your commands below
Enter your commands below

C:\...>SET "v="

C:\....>SET "path="

C:\....>SET "file="

C:\....>SET "v="

C:\....>GOTO :vCheck

C:\...>if not defined v goto :vPrompt

C:\....>SET /p "v=lcl> " Am I supposed to see more than this?

Comment: This is hardly readable in a comment... Anyway, you can see to what values all the variables are expanded; perhaps you can see an error then. What values are the `%globalparam?%` variables set to?

Comment: The %globalparam% variables didn't seem to be set to anything so I deleted it and reran and it didn't seem to change. When I ran it again after that, I only saw the GOTO :vcheck, if not defined v.., and  SET /p "v=lcl >" lines. I don't think there is an error there.

Comment: Overwriting the [`path` environment variable](https://ss64.com/nt/path.html) as `SET "path=%globalparam2%"` is not a good idea because it's Windows `cmd` vital  one. Use another variable name e.g. `SET "_path=%globalparam2%"`.